# Undefined variable id in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this todo list project.

#### My model

```
class Model_lists extends CI_Model {

function Model_list(){
    parent::__construct();
}

function list_get($id){
    $this->load->database();
    $query = $this->db->get_where('lists', array('id'=>$id));
    return $query->row_array();
}
```

#### My Controller

```
public function view_list($id){
    $this->load->model('model_lists');
    $data["query"] = $this->model_lists->list_get($id);
    $this->load->view('lists/view_list',$data);
}
```

#### List view

```
<?php
 echo $query['list_by'];
?>
```

However, when I access the view I get 2 PHP errors

1) Message: Missing argument 1 for Lists::view_list() 
2) Message: Undefined variable: id

This is how I call the list:

```
<a class="view_list" href="<?php echo site_url("lists/view_list?lid={$row->list_id}");?>"><i class="icon-eye"> </i></a>
```

Comment: Because it is `lid` not `id`?

Comment: @u_mulder Changing lid= to id= doesn't change anything in the errors, I still get those 2 errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your site url is not correct. The error is because no id is being passed and in CI (unless you have set to use query arrays) then the url is of the format www.example.com/controller/method/argument

So try:

```
href="<?php echo site_url('lists/view_list/'.$row->list_id); ?>"
```

In the docs:
http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html#site_url

Comment: And since you are using row_array you may need to refer to the id as $row['id'] although not certain about that hence the comment.

Comment: PS You really should also be checking to see if id is set or not. Try using public function view_list($id=FALSE){  which will set the id to FALSE if not set and not just fail. You can then check to see if id is not false and if so deal with that error. Also in you model you assume a result set is returned which it might not be. ie you need to deal with the situation that the id sent is not found in the database.

Comment: Hey @PaulID it works as you suggested `view_list/'.$row->list_id`  what do I have to change if I want it to look like `view_list/lid=?'.$row->list_id` ?

Comment: It is fairly straight forward but you can no longer use the url helpers. You can read about it here http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html#enabling-query-strings but it is just a few config settings.